# Change background colour and text colour on click

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

What I have been trying -unsuccessfully- to achieve is to change the colour of the background **and** the text by clicking one `<a>` element, randomly rotating amongst several colour combinations.

My default colours are:

```
color: #1B1725;
background-color: #A30B37;
```

I would like to use, at least, three colour combinations more (for the sake of this example, those three other combinations can be basic colours).

Edit for further development:

I need just one button that toggles between three colour combinations (not random colours).

What I have tried so far:

```
    function changeColor(combo) {
  if(combo=="combo1"){
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#FEFAE0";
    document.body.style.color = "red";   
  }else if(combo=="combo1"){
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
    document.body.style.color = "white";
  }  
}
```

Using this, it changes from the default colours to the "combo1" colours. I would need that button to keep changing on click.

Comment: You should also include what you tried to accomplish what you need. Otherwise this is not a valid question.

Comment: maybe create a css class with all the style changes and just add that class to the element on button click?

Comment: toggle classes...

Comment: Updated in order to add the piece of code I have tried.

Answer (score 2):

You can generate random colors like this:

```
// Generate random colors
var bg = Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
var text = Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
```

> OR

```
// To generate predefined colors
function getRandomInt(max) {
 return Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
}
var colors = ["000000","FEFEFE","FFFAAA"];
var bg = colors[getRandomInt(colors.length)];
var text = colors[getRandomInt(colors.length)];
```

> Finally

```
var div = document.getElementById('mydiv');
var a= document.getElementById('atagid');
a.onclick = function() {
  div.style.backgroundColor = "#"+bg;
  div.style.color= "#"+text;
}
```

Comment: you can target the HTML element with this `document.querySelector("html")`

Comment: Ye that could work as well.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. However, I don't want to generate random colours; the button should, on click, toggle between a series of predefined colour combinations.

Comment: Oh ok I have made those changes in the answer. Please refer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is sandbox example: https://codesandbox.io/s/currying-cherry-nt80k?file=/index.html

```
function getColorChange(){
    var x = 1
    var a = "black"

    var intervalID = setInterval(function () {
        document.getElementById("changeColor").style.backgroundColor = a;
        if (x == 1) {
            a = "green"
        }
        if (x == 2 ) {
            a="red"
        }
        if (++x === 4) {
            window.clearInterval(intervalID);
        }
    }, 5000);
}
```

Comment: You can use as much as you want  color...